# Custom Query in Spring JPA Repository with Pagination

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, data-paging

I have tried implementing JPA Repository with Spring Boot it works fine.
Now if i try to implement custom query in interface which extends JpaRepository using @Query Annotation it works fine returns List of beans.(using NamedQuery).
Now when i try to use pagination for custom method/query it doesn't work.

Code :

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/custompages/{pageNumber}")
public String getAllEmployeesUsingNamedQueryWithPaging(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber,Model model)
{
    Page<Employee> page = employeeService.getAllEmployeesUsingNamedQueryWithPaging(pageNumber);

    System.out.println("current page "+page);
    System.out.println("current page content"+page.getContent());

     int current = page.getNumber() + 1;
    int begin = Math.max(1, current - 5);
    int end = Math.min(begin + 10, page.getTotalPages());

    model.addAttribute("empList", page.getContent());
    model.addAttribute("empPages", page);
    model.addAttribute("beginIndex", begin);
    model.addAttribute("endIndex", end);
    model.addAttribute("currentIndex", current);

    return "employeeWorkbench";
}
```

Service

```
@Override
public Page<Employee> getAllEmployeesUsingNamedQueryWithPaging(Integer  
pageNumber) {

    PageRequest pageRequest =
            new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, 
    Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
    return   
employeeDao.getAllEmployeesUsingNamedQueryWithPaging(pageRequest);
}
```

Dao

```
@Transactional
public interface EmployeeDao  extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

@Query(name="HQL_GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BY_ID")//Works Fine
public List<Employee> getEmpByIdUsingNamedQuery(@Param("empId") Long
empId);     

@Query(name="HQL_GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE") //throws exception
public Page<Employee> getAllEmployeesUsingNamedQueryWithPaging(Pageable     
pageable);  
}
```

NamedQuery

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<query name="HQL_GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE">from Employee</query>

<query name="HQL_GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE_BY_ID">from Employee where id = 
:empId</query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for
>   TypedQuery [java.lang.Long] is incompatible with query return type
>   [class com.mobicule.SpringBootJPADemo.beans.Employee]

I just want to have pagination functionality provided by Spring JPA Repository for custom methods and query also.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: if instead of using a named query in xml, you put the query directly in the `@Query("from Employee")` does it change the behavior? also the @Transactional on the repository is redundant. Also for queries this simple you'd be better off just using the `findAll` the repository already has.

Comment: also the error is implying that for some reason (not obvious to me) it thinks that the query specified should return a Long and not Employees

Comment: @xenoterracide : Thanks for response. I tried with simply @Query("from Employee") but this will return me List<Employee> and NOT Page<Employee>. My motive is to use JpaRepositories build in Paging Functionality For my custom queries also. And as you said i used findAll this works fine with no issues even works well with pagination also.but i want to have same functionality for my custom queries also.

Comment: I have searched  for this query i got know that when JpaRepository executes its method findAll,findBy......etc with paging it runs 2 queries ---one for count and other for actual data.

Comment: yes that count is intentional... so it knows how many pages it has. If you have the return type specified as `Page<Employee>` you should not get a List, you should only get a List if you ask for a List or a sub interface of List (such as Iterable)

Comment: @xenoterracide : i am not expecting List<Employee> i want Page<Employee> only. because i want pagination

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but for some reason simply doing `from Entity` causes the "id" to be returned, instead you need to provide the entity returned in the select, like `select f from Foo f`

```
public interface FooRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, Long> {

@Query( "select f from Foo f" )
Page<Foo> findAllCustom( Pageable pageable );

Page<Foo> findAllByBarBazContaining( String baz, Pageable pageable );
}
```

I received the same error, with just `from Foo`. I also believe you can reference these by name to the xml file as you were. [here's my full code](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/spring-data-aggregate-persist/src/9cbccbf8dcff092206bcb470ff6a08cd15b49491/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/FooRepo.java?at=master)

further testing says that `from Foo f` also works, I do not know why the alias is required, perhaps it is part of the JPQL spec.

Here is a test showing how to do simple paging, sorting by one property and sorting by multiple properties

```
@Test
public void testFindAllCustom() throws Exception {
    Page<Foo> allCustom = fooRepo.findAllCustom( pageable );

    assertThat( allCustom.getSize(), is( 2 ) );

    Page<Foo> sortByBazAsc = fooRepo.findAllCustom( new PageRequest( 0, 2, Sort.Direction.ASC, "bar.baz" ) );

    assertThat( sortByBazAsc.iterator().next().getBar().getBaz(), is( "2baz2bfoo" ) );

    Page<Foo> complexSort = fooRepo.findAllCustom( new PageRequest( 0, 2, new Sort(
            new Sort.Order( Sort.Direction.DESC, "bar.baz" ),
            new Sort.Order( Sort.Direction.ASC, "id" )
    ) ) );

    assertThat( complexSort.iterator().next().getBar().getBaz(), is( "baz1" ) );
}
```

Comment: changing the query worked.Now i am able to have Jpa pagination functionality for Custom Queries as well. Thank !!! Cheers....!!!!

Comment: you should make this your accepted answer, upvotes are nice too

Comment: @xenoterracide please look at this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434058/how-to-implement-pagination-in-spring-boot-with-hibernate

Comment: @NadeemAhmed if that works that doesn't really explain what happened here, other than "bug". I've got various working paged specifications and `@Query` as well as the simple method parser. All I can say is, I too get the exception described in the askers post.

Comment: @NadeemAhmed oh looking at it again that is doing a sort by DESC, mine is allowing for you to change the sort with a PageRequest

Comment: @NadeemAhmed I've updated this to include examples of dynamic sorting

Comment: For some very strange reason I have this problem only when I run an integration test with h2db. The query works fine with or without the "select f" part of the "select f from Foo", but only with MySQL. With H2 I got the illegal argument exception. Any help?

Comment: ok, i found the problem and it's quite weird. the main query is a bit complex, with several inner and left fetch joins. I wrote both the query and the count query as select f from foo...; now, if i run it against mysql, the query works fine. h2db instead, needs "select count(f) from foo" as count query. Hope this would help